# C vs. Python - operator precedence in conditional statements

Tags: c++, python, c, operator-precedence, comparison-operators

How does the C process a conditional statement such as `n >= 1 <= 10`?

I initially thought that it would get evaluated as `n >= 1 && 1 <= 10`, as it would be evaluated in Python. Since `1 <= 10` is always true, the second porition of the `and` is redundant (the boolean value of `X && True` is equivalent to the boolean value of `X`).

However, when I run it with `n=0`, the conditional gets evaluated to true. In fact, the conditional always seems to evaluate to true.

This was the example I was looking at:

```
if (n >= 1 <= 10)
  printf("n is between 1 and 10\n");
```

Comment: And are you asking us to answer the question for you? How will that help you? have you tried compiling it?

Comment: Did you read chapter about operator precedence first?

Comment: I believe it isn't legal, I'm pretty sure you'd have to say if( n >= 1 && n <= 10), but don't quote me on that - hence my leaving it as a comment and not the answer. Once you set it up that way, the precedence would be left to right. And I think C and C++ use "lazy" checks, so.. if the left side fails, it won't even bother checking the right side.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6961643/827263); see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6961728/827263).

Comment: Question has been reworded to fit the rules

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`>=` operator is evaluated from left to right, so it is equal to:

```
if( ( n >= 1 ) <= 10)
    printf("n is between 1 and 10\n");
```

The first `( n >= 1 )` is evaluated either as true or false, which is equal to either 1 or 0. Then that result of 1 or 0 is compared to `result <= 10` which will always evaluate to true. 
Thus the statement `printf("n is between 1 and 10\n");` will always be printed

Answer (score 4):

It's [evaluated left to right](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx) like this:

```
n = 5;

if (n >= 1 <= 10)
// then
if (1 <= 10)
// then 
if (1)
```

It first checks if `n >= 1`. If it is, it evaluates to `1`, otherwise `0`. This leads to the next evaluation, `1 <= 10`, which evaluates to `1` as well. Note that this also succedes:

```
n = 5;
if (n >= 3 == 1)
```

Because it's evaluated like this:

```
n = 5;
if (n >= 3 == 1) // but you should never write code like this
// then
if (1 == 1)
// then
if (1)
```

Also note why it works with `n = 0`

```
n = 0;
if (n >= 1 <= 10)
// then
if (0 <= 10) // 0 isn't greater or equal to 1, so 0 (false) is "returned"
// then
if (1) // but 0 is less than or equal to 10, so it evaluates as 1 (true)
```