# Why does (a == b == c) inside if statement in C not work?

Tags: c, if-statement

I have a question:
Why does (a == b == c) inside if statement in C not work?

For example, I have this code:

```
int naxes1[1] = {6};
int naxes2[1] = {6};
int naxes3[1] = {6};

if (naxes1[0]  == naxes2[0] == naxes3[0])
    printf("first doesnot work\n");

if (naxes1[0]  == naxes2[0] && naxes1[0]== naxes3[0])
    printf("second works\n");
```

why?

I went through following links:
[Usage of greater than, less than operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961643/usage-of-greater-than-less-than-operators)

Comment: Simply change the programming language. AFAIK in JavaScript you may use operator ===.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: The question isn't about `===`, it's about `a == b == c`. Which doesn't work in JavaScript, either (except with booleans, like C).

Comment: @Quentin: This is my point, you can do it if you have booleans (and you pick the right values), but it's unlikely to be what you actually wanted.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's an original definition of "works", I guess :p Note that it will actually compile for a great variety of types, provided there's an implicit conversion from `bool`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's evaluated like this:

```
if ((naxes1[0] == naxes2[0]) == naxes3[0])
//  ^----------------------^---- Note
```

...and the result of that inner expression isn't the value in `naxes1[0]` or `naxes2[0]`, it's a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Order of operations. The first `==` will result  a `true` or `1`. then when you compare `1` to `naxes[0]` you get

```
1 == 6
```

which is false so you get `0` and it does not print.