# How "a<b<c" or "a>b>c" are evaluated in C

Tags: c

I found this question in many interviews and my teacher asked me the same the main doubt was that if I include `<stdbool.h>` in C99 standard will that evaluate this as `(true)<c`  or `(false)>c`. Need a more clear answer than the linked post --> [Usage of greater than, less than operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961643/usage-of-greater-than-less-than-operators]) .

How `a<b<c`  or `a>b>c` are evaluated in C
for example in the following code.

```
# include<stdbool.h> 
int main(void){
    int a = 1,b=2,c=3;
    if(a<b<c)
        printf("a great b great c");
    }
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: I assume that you want to evaluate in its mathematical sence: b is between a and c. This does not work, because independently of the execution order, the result of the first subexpression is 0 or 1, depending on what is correct. The second comparision is than compared against this result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of greater than, less than operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961643/usage-of-greater-than-less-than-operators)

Comment: @BoPersson can you answer the same as i have mentioned what I'm actually seeking no one mentioned the same in the answer.

Comment: `<stdbool.h>` just contains things like `#define true 1` and doesn't affect the result at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From standard [itself](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.8) (Relational operators footnotes)

> The expression `a<b<c` is not interpreted as in ordinary mathematics.
>   As the syntax indicates, it means `(a<b)<c`; in other words, if `a`
>   is less than `b`, compare `1` to `c`; otherwise, compare `0` to `c`.

Comment: so what is `1<c` basically? or it is `true<c`?

Comment: @OptimusPrime.: No it's comparing integer 1 with value of `c`.

Comment: @ikegami C99 supports bool which is defined in stdbool.h for your info

Answer (score 0):

Operator associativity dictates that `a<b<c` is equivalent to `(a<b)<c` (as opposed to `a<(b<c)`).

If `a` is less than `b`, `a<b` evaluates to `1`. Otherwise, `0`.

If the value returned by `a<b` (`1` or `0`) is less than `c`, the whole evaluates to `1`. Otherwise, `0`.

---

From the [spec](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html)

> Each of the operators `<` (less than), `>` (greater than), `<=` (less than or equal to), and `>=` (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is false.) The result has type int.