# Efficiency of multiple greater than/less than operation inside a single statement

Tags: c, performance

I am currently a beginner learning C and come across a statement  from Stackoverflow [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961643/chaining-multiple-greater-than-less-than-operators), that C associate this operator (<) from left to right.

What i conclude from the answer is that, C is just gonna run it left to right one by one instead of what human perceive as (a<b<c), but i also assume that if two operators has the same Associativity, C is also gonna run it from left to right, is this correct?.

The second part is, `if (a<b<c)` is actually written `((a<b) && (b<c))` wouldn't it be more efficient to write a code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 7 ;

int main() {
   
   if (x > 20)
   {
     printf("y");
   }
   else 
   {
       if (x == 7) 
       {
           printf("n");
       }
       else if (x > 7)
       {
            printf("z");
       }
       else 
       {
           printf("h");
       }
   }
    
    return 0;
}
```

rather than this:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int x = 7;

int main() {
   
   if (7 < x && x <= 20)
   {
     printf("z");
   }
   else if (x > 20)
   {
        printf("y");
   }
   else if (x == 7)
   {
         printf("n");
   }
   else {
        printf("h");
   }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Because the 2nd code does more comparison operation than the 1st one,is this true?.

Comment: It is not sensible to compare the codes for efficiency, since they produce different results, e. g. for x = 20.

Comment: Associativity is not the same as order of execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, `&&` short-circuits. That means the right-hand side is not evaluated if the left-hand side is false. Similarly for `||` and a left-hand side that's true. In both cases the right-hand side does not influence the outcome.

This is important in code like `if (p && p->q)` where the pointer `p` is dereferenced only if it's not `NULL`.

Having said that, the performance of such comparisons is virtually instant. They map pretty directly to CPU instructions, unlike `printf`. Your code's speed will be limited by that printing.