# How do I break loop in do while?

Tags: c, loops, do-while, break

How can I break the `do while` loop here in my code? The program should loop until the user inputs a valid year from the category.

When I enter the valid input, the `printf` still shows up even if it is meant to stop.

Here is the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  float year;

  do {
    printf("Please input your year of birth :");
    scanf("%f", &year);

    if ((year >= 1946) && (year  <= 1964))
      printf("You belong to the baby boomer generation \n");
    else if ((year  >= 1965) && (year  <= 1980))
      printf("You belong to the Generation X \n");
    else if ((year  >= 1981) && (year  <= 1996))
      printf("You belong to the Millenials/Generation Y \n"); 
    else if ((year  >= 1997) && (year  <= 2012))
      printf("You belong to the Zoomers/Generation Z \n"); 
  } while(1946 > year < 2012);
}
```

Comment: I guess it was break in C lang. -> https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-break-continue-statement

Comment: `while(1946 > year < 2012);`.   This does not do what you think it does.

Comment: `float year;` How many decimals do you expect for a year? Why not make it an `int`?

Comment: @Airgelo, if your question has been answered, consider marking one as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` condition does not work as you expect. For the computer, `1946 > year < 2012` is `(1946 > year) < 2021`; `1946 > year` will be either `0` or `1`, so in the end you have `0 < 2021` (or `1 < 2021`), which is always true, and the loop won't stop.

Try to change it to e.g. `1946 > year && year < 2012`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6961728/5471218 for details.

Comment: When `1946 > year` is true, you have `1 < 2021` which is also true.

Comment: @WilliamPursell true, that's why I wrote "will be 0 most of the time" ;) But good point, I'll update my answer to show that the comparison result is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
(1946 > year < 2012)
```

should be

```
(year > 1946 && year < 2012)
```

and `break;` should be used if you want to break it somewhere like

```
if(year == 2000)
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an else condition to break the loop.

```
if ((year >= 1946) && (year  <= 1964))
  printf("You belong to the baby boomer generation \n");
else if ((year  >= 1965) && (year  <= 1980))
  printf("You belong to the Generation X \n");
else if ((year  >= 1981) && (year  <= 1996))
  printf("You belong to the Millenials/Generation Y \n"); 
else if ((year  >= 1997) && (year  <= 2012))
  printf("You belong to the Zoomers/Generation Z \n"); 
else
    break;
```