what shoud I do for "suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of '==' [-Wparentheses]"?
if ((board[0][0]) == (board[0][1]) == (board[0][2])){
        return 1;
    }
    if ((board[1][0]) == (board[1][1]) == (board[1][2])){
        return 2;
    }
    if ((board[2][0]) == (board[2][1]) == (board[2][2])){
        return 3;
    }

I am trying to check if certain elements in an array(board[3][3]) to return a number if specific elements are equal.
but I am getting this warning :
suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of '=='[-Wparentheses]

You can't make comparison like this, you need to do board[0][0] == board[0][1] after that you need to add an boolean operator like && or || e.g board[0][0] == board[0][1] && board[0][0] == board[0][2]

Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961643/chaining-multiple-greater-than-less-than-operators

The comparison a == b == c is equal to (a == b) == c, which compares the boolean result of a == b with c.

As an aside, I would write a function row_equal and then use if (row_equal(board[0])) to save on the repetition.
