# Operator overloading in C?

Tags: c, operator-overloading

Is it possible to do operator overloading or something similar (inline function?) in C? I know that c does not support `class`, but could I make an operator for a `struct`?

I cannot find anything about this online, because Google will ignore '+' so if I try to google this I only get C++ results.

Comment: Many C compilers support inline functions, but C doesn't have operator overloading.  In fact, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99), C99 supports inline functions as part of the standard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417413/operator-overloading-in-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't do that in C.  Use C++ if you want to overload operators.

You *can* put function pointers inside a structure if you want a sort of C++ object-like behaviour.

Comment: Do what?  Put a function pointer in a structure?  `struct x { void (*functionPointer)(void) };`

Comment: Operator overloading is in fact the reason I switched to C++ for a project I worked on -- it is a lot more convenient to use an overloaded operator than a normal function when doing vector math.

Answer (score 4):

No it is not possible.

By the way, you can remove `C++` from google search results if you add `-"C++"` to your search query.

Answer (score 1):

C++ introduced an important and interesting feature which is operator overloading.

So you will have to use it if you want to use this feature.

Answer (score 0):

C does not support operator overloading or having functions inside structs.  You will need to use C++ for those features.

Answer (score 0):

C does not support operator overloading.