# Is it possible to overload the operator + with char strings?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, concatenation

I want to simplify the using of strings like in java.

so i can write `"count "+6;` and get a string "count 6"
with std::string it's possible to concatenate two strings or std::string with char string.

i wrote 2 functions

```
template<typename T>
inline static std::string operator+(const std::string str, const T gen){
    return str + std::to_string(gen);
}

template<typename T>
inline static std::string operator+(const T gen, const std::string str){
    return std::to_string(gen) + str;
}
```

to concatenate std::string with numbers, but cannot write something like `"count "+6;` because `"count "` is a const char[] and not a std::string.

it works with `std::string("count")+" is "+6+" and it works also with double "+1.234;` , but thats not really pretty =)

is there a possibility to do the same without starting with std::string("")

```
template<typename T>
inline static std::string operator+(const char* str, const T gen){
    return str + std::to_string(gen);
}
```

this method doesn't work and i get an compiler error

```
error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [1]' to binary 'operator+'
```

Comment: Asking for C++, why did you add tag for a different language? (rhetorical question, just **don't**)

Comment: yes i'm using c++, but i believe overloading operators is also available in c, but not sure. sorry if not

Comment: [C does not support operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3417443/4342498)

Comment: Ok, you apparently don't know C. So just stick to the rule not to add tags for languages you don't know. (note the first sentence implies C doe not allow user-overloading of operators)

Comment: thanks for the information, i will memorize it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You cannot overload operators for built-in types *only*; one of the two types involved in the operation must either be a class type or an enumeration.

What you could do to make things more palatable is construct strings on the fly by using a user-defined literal:

```
"count"s + 3.1415;
```

Be aware that this is a C++14 feature that may or may not be supported by your compiler yet.

Comment: I clearly mentioned it is C++14. It does not invalidate the answer; it is an option the original poster may simply not be aware of.

Answer (score 3):

When overloading operators, at least one of the operands has to be a user type (while types from the `std` library are considered user types). In other words: Not both operands of `operator+` can be builtin types.

---

Since C++11, there are literal operators available. They make it possible to write

```
"count "_s
```

instead of

```
std::string("count ")
```

Such an operator is defined like this (the name of the following literal operator is `_s`; they have to start with an underscore for custom literal operator overloads):

```
std::string operator ""_s(const char *str, std::size_t len) {
    return std::string(str, len);
}
```

Then, your expression becomes

```
"count "_s + 6
```

In C++14, such an operator is [already available](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s), and named more conveniently `s` (the standard may use operator names without a leading underscore), so it becomes

```
"count "s + 6
```