# Writing programs with structs and functions in C

Tags: c

I am studying for an Intro to C test that requires me to write functions that involve structs. The question only asks me to write the function, but I want to write an entire code that runs so I can put in numbers and see if my code is running properly. I think I wrote the function properly, I just don't know how to code numbers in and have it print out the numbers.

This is the question.

[image: The question.]

Here is what I've written for the above question.

```
struct complex_numb Add_Complex(struct complex_numb C1, struct complex_numb C2){

struct complex_numb C3;

C3.real = C1.real + C2.real;
C3.imaginary = C1.imaginary + C2.imaginary;

return (C3);

};
```

We aren't using typedef yet.

I thought it would be something like this, but it isnt working.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

struct complex_numb Add_Complex(struct complex_numb C1, struct complex_numb C2);

int main(){

struct complex_numb{
    float real;
    float imaginary;
};

Add_Complex(1,2,3,4);

printf("%f %f", C3.real, C3.imaginary);

}

struct complex_numb Add_Complex(struct complex_numb C1, struct complex_numb C2){

struct complex_numb C3;
C3.real = C1.real + C2.real;
C3.imaginary = C1.imaginary + C2.imaginary;


return (C3);

};
```

Comment: Why are you passing in 4 things as a parameter in Add_Complex?

Comment: You aren't creating a C1 and a C2 structure and passing those to `Add_Complex()`.  You're invoking undefined behaviour, and your compiler should be shrieking at you.  If it isn't, you need to turn on more compilation warnings (or get a better/newer compiler).

Comment: Wouldn't there be four numbers because there are 2 real numbers and 2 imaginary numbers? That was my logic, I'm not really sure as to how it is all put together as I am still learning about functions and structs.

Comment: @beginner check my answer below working code.

Comment: Don't define your own types. C provides a `_Complex` type already.

Comment: @Olaf I think he is trying to understand basic concept of something like "Operator Overloading" no?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI: C does not allow operators to be overloaded by users.

Comment: @Olaf I know but it is pseudo op. overloading as you are technically adding two non-primative datatypes the way the user wants.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI: The term "operator overloading" is pretty clear. Using a function **with distinct name** to generate a result from input is clearly not related. Where do you see an overloaded operator or even an overloaded function??

Comment: Note: `return` is a statement. The parentheses are not required and potentially troublesome, as they can shadow syntax errors. And "but it isnt working." is not a **specific** problem description. Read [ask] and follow the advice.

Comment: @Olaf I understand, but this can be seen as "overloading" the + sign even though the + sign is in the form of a function name Add_Complex. You can not simply do Operator overloading in C, and simply compiler does not know what C1 + C2 means, therefore abstracting the addition symbol in a function call that is meant to add the two non-primative datatypes the way he wants it. I understand what you are saying, but isn't this a solution to "operator overloading" in C?

Comment: @Olaf this kind of explains what I am trying to say? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417413/operator-overloading-in-c

Comment: @OmidCompSCI: Please read the definition of "operator overloading". with your argumentation, every function would overload something, be it a bunch of operators. It is **not** operator overloading, nor related!

Comment: @Olaf many people in that link above agree with me.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI: Well, you must see a different site than what I see. Did you even read the answers, including the accepted one?? It is fine you know a term. But you should not use it where inappropriate. That discussion is pointless. You apparently refuse to accept you are wrong. I'm out of this.

Comment: @Olaf thanks, but the obvious answer is obviously C does not have operator overloading, but there is a theoretical psuedo way of doing it which is what the other answers that have been upvoted explain. Some people want theoretical and other solutions rather than straight up no, because I am pretty sure they already know there is no Op. Overload, but "what is an alternative, and how can I achieve it?" is something that people want to learn about. Thanks.

Comment: @beginner please accept my answer below so others can use it as a reference for a similar question asked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your C1 and C2, add those values to the attributes inside your struct, and create your return object of complex_numb which called "C3" and have that = to the result of the function call that takes in C1 and C2. Changed your struct using typedef and moved it out of main. Here is a compiling and working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
        float real;
        float imaginary;
    }complex_numb;

complex_numb Add_Complex(complex_numb C1, complex_numb C2);

    int main()
    { 
        complex_numb C1;
        C1.real = 1;
        C1.imaginary = 2;
        complex_numb C2;
        C2.real = 3;
        C2.imaginary = 4;

    //Add_Complex(1,2,3,4);
    complex_numb C3;
    C3 = Add_Complex(C1,C2);
    printf("%f %f", C3.real, C3.imaginary);

    }

 complex_numb Add_Complex(complex_numb C1, complex_numb C2){

    complex_numb C3;
    C3.real = C1.real + C2.real;
    C3.imaginary = C1.imaginary + C2.imaginary;


    return (C3);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your actual and formal parameters do not match. And when you return c3, you do not store the structure before you try and print its contents.