# How to eliminate unused elements in structures?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, embedded

### Background

I am working on a modular architecture for embedded devices where different abstraction layers have to communicate  with each others. The current approach is to have plenty of functions, variables and defines mangled with the module name they belong to.

This approach is a bit painful and I would like to define some kind of common interfaces for the API. The key idea is to get a better understanding of what modules share the same HAL interface.

### Proposal

I would like to use a OOP inspired architecture where I use structures as interfaces. All these structures are populated statically.

This solution looks nice but I might waste a lot of memory because the compiler doesn't know how to chop off structures and only keep what it really needs to.

The following example can be built with or without `-DDIRECT` and the behavior should be exactly the same.

### Example

#### Source (test.c)

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int do_foo(int a) {
    return 42 * a;
}

#ifdef DIRECT
int (*foo)(int) = do_foo;
int (*bar)(int);
int storage;
#else
struct foo_ts {
    int (*do_foo)(int);
    int (*do_bar)(int);
    int storage;
} foo = {.do_foo = do_foo};
#endif

int main(char argc) {
    #ifdef DIRECT
    return foo(argc);
    #else
    return foo.do_foo(argc);
    #endif
}
```

#### Makefile

```
CFLAGS=-O2 -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -g --specs=nosys.specs
CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc

upper=$(shell echo $(1) | tr a-z A-Z)

EXEC=direct.out with_struct.out

all: $(EXEC)

%.out:test.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -D$(call upper,$(basename $@)) -o $@ test.c
    size $@
```

#### Output

One can notice that the memory footprint used with the `struct` variant is bigger because the compiler doesn't allow itself to remove the unused members.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -g \
                  --specs=nosys.specs -DDIRECT -o direct.out test.c
size direct.out
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    992    1092      36    2120     848 direct.out
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -g \
                  --specs=nosys.specs -DWITH_STRUCT -o with_struct.out test.c
size with_struct.out
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    992    1100      28    2120     848 with_struct.out
```

### Question

With this example I demonstrate that using a structure is good for readability and modularity, but it could decrease efficiency and it increases the memory usage.

Is there a way to get the advantages of both solutions? Said differently, is there a way to tell the compiler to be smarter?

### OOP?

Following the comments on this question, one suggestion is to use C++ instead. Unfortunately, the same issue would occur because a Class with unused members will never be simplified by the compiler. So I am falling in the same trap with both languages.

Another raised point was the reason for unused members in structures. To address this question we can imagine a generic 3-axes accelerometer used in an application where only 1 axis is used. The HAL for this accelerometer could have the methods `read_x_acc`, `read_y_acc` and `read_z_acc` while only `read_x_acc` is used by the application.

If I declare a class in C++ or a structure in C the function pointers for unused methods/functions will still consume memory for nothing.

Comment: It is not a good idea to imitate OP in the C.. Use C++ instead or write in C. Mixing makes code difficult to read, error prone, full of conditional compilations ec

Comment: see the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing

Comment: @PeterJ True, but as mentioned by Jay Atkinson [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/3036/92508), C++ is a very very powerful tool much like a two-edged sword that can cut both your arm and leg off if not educated and disciplined properly. I am afraid it would be more complicated to train my coworker than stick to a language they know already.

Comment: @nowox so write in C and do not try to imitate C++

Comment: @ChungkilKim I don't really mind about structure alignment, I simply would like to remove the unused symbols in that structure during the linking.

Comment: @PeterJ I **strongly** disagree, there are a lot of projects using OOP principles in C. The best-known is probably glib/gtk, but even the win32 API is largely object-oriented, still C.

Comment: @PeterJ I am writing C, structures are part of C as function pointers are. The mangling is much worse because you will need to use a lot of pass-through defines such as `#define HAL_FOO modulea_foo`.

Comment: @nowox I'm not sure I understand your question. Is your problem that your "interface" sometimes needs fewer functions? Then separate into several interfaces. If you need inheritance, make the "parent" interface the first member of the derived one.

Comment: STM32 project? (HAL......)

Comment: @FelixPalmen My issue is not really solved in C++ either. An interface or a class with unused members will never be simplified by the compiler either. So with C++ I am falling in the same trap.

Comment: @PeterJ Multi Architecture nRF51/nRF52/STM32/MSP430

Comment: @nowox then don't declare unused members, see my comment above. You have to define interfaces according to the single responsibility principle.

Comment: @Felix Palmen yes they are. Is it the evidence that imitating is the best?   IMO if one writes OOP is best to use OO language.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I believe he understands that removind the declaration would reduce the size. But I think he wants some optimization pass to figure out the unused members/

Comment: @PeterJ there are a lot of good reasons to use C and there are a lot of problems best solved with OOP. What's the best approach depends on a lot of constraints, but C allows for some good OOP styles, so please just respect what the OP wants.

Comment: @nowox  `So with C++ I am falling in the same trap` - definitely not.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya with a sensible design, there's no reason to do so. If you have a module implementing A and a module implementing B, which is a superset of A, you typically use inheritance, and that's not too complicated with C structs. But I have to admit, from the question it's not entirely clear to me whether this is the exact problem.

Comment: @nowox it is generally not a good idea on the compiler to remove unused members from both structs or classes because it doesn't know in a translation unit what other modules are using the same struct. Yes, if it can statically prove that pointers to this type are never passed out, maybe! But with types like `void*` it is very difficult to reason.

Comment: @FelixPalmen *My issue is not really solved in C++ either. An interface or a class with unused members will never be simplified by the compiler either. So with C++ I am falling in the same trap* this hints a bit towards the real problem.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya yes, that's the reason I suggest to design the interfaces properly (aka more fine-grained)

Comment: @FelixPalmen ofcourse! These things should be controlled by the programmer and not left to the compiler to optimize.

Comment: I've edited my question to include C++

Comment: You need to explain why you need to use function pointers as struct members. There should only be 2 reasons: either because they are callbacks, or because you are implementing some manner of polymorphism. Is either of this true? If not, then note that `x.func(y)` is not "more OO" than `func(x, y)`, it is only language syntax and has nothing to do with OO program design.

Comment: inherintance never works from large to small or complex to simple, it's the other way round. You always start with the most simple, most generic (yet useful) interface you can think of and derive/inherit from there; to stay with your accelerometer class example, you would define a "class" (real or mimiced) with one accelerometer and have derived classes with more of them. The same applies for member variables and -functions. No waste of space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first show you a possible approach regarding your edit, where your current interface has three functions, but sometimes you would need only one of them. You could define two interfaces:

```
typedef struct I1DAccel
{
    double (*read)(void);
} I1DAccel;

typedef struct I3DAccel
{
    union
    {
        I1DAccel x;
        struct
        {
            double (*read_x)(void);
        };
    };

    union
    {
        I1DAccel y;
        struct
        {
            double (*read_y)(void);
        };
    };

    union
    {
        I1DAccel z;
        struct
        {
            double (*read_z)(void);
        };
    };
} I3DAccel;
```

Then you can make the implementation of the Accelerometer do this:

```
I1DAccel accel_x = { read_x_acc };
I1DAccel accel_y = { read_y_acc };
I1DAccel accel_z = { read_z_acc };
I3DAccel accel =
{
    .read_x = read_x_acc,
    .read_y = read_y_acc,
    .read_z = read_z_acc,
};
```

With proper link-time optimizations, the compiler could then throw away any of these global structs that isn't used by application code.

Of course, you will consume **more** memory if one part of your code requires only `accel_x` while another part requires the whole `accel`. You would have to hunt down these cases manually.

---

Of course, using "interface" `struct`s, you will **always** consume more memory than without them, the pointers have to be stored *somewhere*. Therefore, the typical approach is indeed to just prepend the module name to the functions and call them directly, like e.g. in case of such an accelerometer:

```
typedef int acchndl; // if you need more than one accelerometer

double Accel_read_x(acchndl accel);
double Accel_read_y(acchndl accel);
double Accel_read_z(acchndl accel);
```

This is conceptually similar to what you would do in e.g. C++:

```
class Accel
{
    double read_x();
    double read_y();
    double read_z();
};

double Accel::read_x()
{
    // implementation here
}
```

With the plain C above, instead of an *instance pointer*, you can use any other type of "object handle", like demonstrated with the `typedef` to `int`, which is often an advantage for embedded code.

Answer (score 1):

> This solution looks nice but I might waste a lot of memory because the compiler doesn't know how to chop off structures and only keep what it really needs to.
>   ...
>   Is there a way to get the advantages of both solutions? Said differently, is there a way to tell the compiler to be smarter?

One problem is 'C' compiles things as a module (compilation unit) and there is often no easy way to know what will and will not be used in a structure.  Consider the structure can be passed from module to module as you propose.  When compiling one module, there is no context/information to know that some other module will use the structure or not.

Okay, so that leads to some possible solutions.  `gcc` has the option `-fwhole-program` <sup>See: [-fipa-struct-reorg](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)</sup>  as well as `gold` and **LTO**.  Here you must structure your makefile so that the compiler (code generator) has all of the information available to know if it may remove structure members.  This is not to say that these options will do what you want with a current `gcc`, just that they are a requirement to get things to work.

---

### C++

You can do most anything in 'C' that you can in C++; just not as programmer efficiently.  See: [Operator overloading in 'C'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417413/operator-overloading-in-c/15421178#15421178).  So how might a 'C' compiler implement your virtual functions?  Your C++ virtuals might look like this underneath,

```
struct foo_ts_virtual_table {
    int my_type /* RTTI value for polymorphism. */
    int (*do_foo)(int);
    int (*do_bar)(int);
} foo_vtable = {.my_type = ENUM_FOO_TS; .do_foo = foo};

struct foo_ts {
    void * vtable; /* a foo_ts_virtual_table pointer */
    int storage;
} foo = {.vtable = foo_vtable};
```

This is a win memory wise if you have multiple `foo_ts` structures.  A down side of this is that a function pointer is difficult to in-line.  **Often a simple functions body maybe less than the call overhead on an ARM CPU.**  This results in more code memory and slower execution.

C++ compilers will be geared to eliminate these extraneous functions, just because this is a common issue in C++. A 'C' compilers analysis is confounded by your custom code/notation and the language definition of structure and compilation units.

---

Other possibilities are to wrap the function calls in macros and emit data to a non-linked section.  You can examine the non-linked section to see whether or not to include a function (and pointer) in the final link.  What is a win or not depends on lots of different design objectives.  It is certainly going to complicate the build process and confound other developers.

As well, the [ARM Linux *MULTI_CPU*](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/glue-proc.h) maybe of interest.  This is only to eliminate function pointers if only one 'type' is needed at run time.

If you insist on function pointers, there will be occasions where this actually generates more code.  C++ compilers will do book keeping to see when a virtual might be in-lined as well as possibly not emitting unused member functions in a virtual table (and the implementation of the function).  These issues maybe more pronounced than the extra structure overhead.