# Magic methods on other programming languages

Tags: language-agnostic, magic-methods

Python has such methods as `__add__`, `__mul__`, `__cmp__` and so on (called [magic methods](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/)), which are used as a class methods and can give a different meaning to adding(`+`), multiplying(`*`), comparing(`==`), ... two instances of a class. My question is do other languages have a similar method? I'm familiar with Java, C++, ruby and PHP, but never came across such a thing. I know all four have a constructor method which corresponds to `__init__`, but what about other magic methods?

I tried googling "Magic methods in other programming languages" but nothing related showed up, probably they got different names on different languages.

Comment: c++ has operator overloading.

Comment: Here is the list: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading#Catalog

Comment: Not everything can be implemented using operator overloading though (such as `__len__`). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657627/why-does-python-use-magic-methods/39340307

Comment: If you're looking for more than a simple "yes", your question might be too broad, covering too many languages and/or too many methods. What sort of answer are you looking for?

Comment: @JaMiT, I know it covers a lot of languages. But if you know one language that have "magic methods" you are welcome to answer.

Comment: @John "operator overloading", that was a phrase I was looking for. Tnx

Comment: @Babydesta So you are looking for an answer that covers any one language (other than Python) and the three magic methods called out in your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, having too much "magic" in a language is a sign of bad language design. Maybe that is why there are not many languages which have magic methods?

Magic like this creates a two-class system: the language designer can add new magic methods to the language, but the programmer is restricted to only use the methods that the High Priest Of Language Design allows them to. In general, it should be possible for the programmer to do as much possible *without* requiring to change the language specification.

For example, in Scala, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `::`, `|`, `&`, `||`, `&&`, `**`, `^`, `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, and so on and so forth, are simply legal identifiers. So, if you want to implement your own version of multiplication for your own objects, you just write a method named `*`. This is just a boring old standard method, there is absolutely nothing "magic" about it.

Conversely, *any* method can be called using operator notation, i.e. without a dot. And any method that takes exactly one argument can be called without parentheses in operator notation.

This does not only apply to methods. Also, any type constructor with exactly two type arguments can be used in infix notation, so if I have

```scala
class ↔️[A, B]
```

I can do

```scala
class Foo extends (String ↔️ Int)
```

which is the same as

```scala
class Foo extends ↔️[String, Int]
```

Well … I kinda lied: there is some syntactic sugar in Scala:

- `foo()` is translated to `foo.apply()` if there is no method named `foo` in scope. This allows you to effectively overload the function call operator.
- `foo.bar = baz` is translated to `foo.bar_=(baz)`. This allows you to effectively overload property assignment. (This is how you write setters in Scala.)
- `foo(bar) = baz` is translated to `foo.update(bar, baz)`. This allows you to effectively overload index assignment. (This is how you write array or dictionary access in Scala, for example).
- `!foo` (and a couple of others) are translated to `foo.unary_!`.
- `foo += bar` will try to call the `+=` method of `foo`, i.e. it is equivalent to `foo.+=(bar)`. But if this fails *and* `foo` is a valid lvalue, *and* `foo` has a method named `+`, then Scala will also try `foo = foo + bar` instead.

Also, precedence, associativity, and fixity are fixed in Scala: they are determined by the first character of the method name. I.e. all methods starting with `*` have the same precedence, all methods starting with `-` have the same precedence, and so on.

Haskell goes a step further: there is no *fundamental* difference between functions and operators. Every function can be used in function call notation and in operator notation. The only difference is lexical: if the function name consists of operator characters, then when I want to use it in function call notation, I have to wrap it in parentheses. OTOH, if the function name consists of alphanumeric characters and I want to use it in operator notation, I need to wrap it in backticks. So, the following are equivalent:

```
a + b
(+) a b

a `plus` b
plus a b
```

For operator usage of functions, you can freely define the fixity, associativity, and precedence, e.g.:

```hs
infixr 15 <!==!>
```

In Ruby, there is a pre-defined set of operators that has corresponding methods, e.g.:

```rb
def +(other)
  plus(other)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 3):

In `C++` [operator overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) is what your are looking for.

`Java` has no native support for operator overloading ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686699/operator-overloading-in-java)).

`C` has no operator overloading ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417413/operator-overloading-in-c)). Thus, a lot of `add`, `mult` and so on functions are written. Often those are macros, because then they can be used for different types. IMHO this is why I like C++ better.

@Alex gave [reference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading#Catalog) to a nice overview of operator overlaoding.

Comment: Java *does* have overloaded operators, but the designers of the language believe that normal programmers are too stupid, so only the language designers are allowed to overload them.